# When and what did Abraham saw Jesus in John 8:56?

Tags: john, jesus, abraham

**John 8:56 New King James Version (NKJV)**

**Your father Abraham rejoiced to see My day, and he saw it and was glad.”**

When did Abraham saw Jesus' day?

In Genesis 22:4

**Genesis 22:4 New King James Version (NKJV)**

**Then on the third day Abraham lifted his eyes and saw the place afar off.**

**THIRD DAY** -> Hints Jesus' death on the cross as a sacrifice for our sins

**LIFTED HIS EYES** -> Hints Luke 16:23 where the rich man LIFTED HIS EYES

**PLACE AFAR OFF** -> The place was never mentioned. However if looked at Luke 16:23, Rich man saw Abraham **AFAR OFF**

Luke 16:23 New King James Version (NKJV)
And being in torments in Hades, he **lifted up his eyes** and saw **Abraham afar off**, and Lazarus in his bosom.

Could it be Abraham was Known as the father of Faith, because he had grace + truth (based on Heb 11:1 and all other hints that the faith of Jesus is of Jesus being grace + truth, substance of things hoped for (grace) evidence of things not seen (truth)  ). 
The truth being seeing Jesus before he was supposed to sacrifice Isaac.
That's why he said "and we will come back to you" to his young men in Gen 22:5.
The young men being faithful and 'able' witnesses in 2 Tim 2:2

So since in Gen 22:4, he saw Jesus' day in Luke 16:23, thus he had the truth that Jesus would take the place of his son Isaac, and he told the faithful young men who were witnesses, that they would be back.

So Abraham saw hell?

Comment: Welcome to BH. My own view is that you are simply connecting similar sounding words together in a somewhat haphazard way and arriving at insubstantial conclusions. I would suggest that that method is not hermeneutic. But that is just my own opinion. Your header question is not grammatical and I do not understand what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer - What did Abraham see? The day of redemption through the Messiah.

Often, when Jesus makes a comment on the Old Testament, he is making reference to something *culturally* familiar to his 1st-century Jewish audience - particularly, the religious leaders. This seems to be one of those cases. The sages have a tradition regarding Abraham and the night when God made his covenant with him in Genesis 15. The text says:

> As the sun was setting, Abram fell into a deep sleep, and **a thick and dreadful darkness came over him**. Then the Lord said to him, “Know for certain that for four hundred years your descendants will be strangers in a country not their own and that they will be enslaved and mistreated there. (Gen. 15:12-13)

and then...

> When the sun had set and darkness had fallen, a smoking firepot with a blazing torch appeared and passed between the pieces. On that day the **Lord made a covenant** with Abram (Gen. 15:17-18)

The entire passage of Genesis 15 - with the cutting of the animals (a covenant cutting ceremony) - seems strange to our modern way of thinking, but not to Abraham.  The covenant cutting ceremony is an ancient Near East custom that all Biblical people would have been familiar with (see [Jeremiah 34:18](https://biblehub.com/jeremiah/34-18.htm))

As far as this text from John, one such Jewish tradition is that when Abraham was in his "deep sleep," God showed him a vision from the days of the Exodus to the **final redemption of the Messiah**. These traditions are found in the Aramaic versions of the Old Testament, called the Targum (Targum Pseudo-Jonathan) or from the Talmud - Genesis Rabbah 44.

It appears that Jesus is referring to this tradition. The Pharisees in John 8 are challenging Jesus' claim that he is the Messiah! Jesus, talking about being "glorified," uses this tradition with Abraham to emphasize who he is.

Another aspect of what Jesus is saying would be (my paraphrase of John 8) "Abraham saw and rejoiced...but here you are, what is your problem? You claim to be son's of Abraham but you can't recognize me as Messiah, nor rejoice!"

Hebrews 11 also alludes to this tradition. Speaking of Abraham's faith:

> All these people were still living by faith when they died. They did not receive the things promised; they only **saw them and welcomed them from a distance** (Heb. 11:13).

One of the greatest barriers to our understanding of the Bible is the cultural context. Many passages of the New Testament - like this one - can only be revealed at the deepest level when we understand the cultural nuances that exist around what is being said. Check out Dr. Sandra Richter, [The Epic of Eden: A Christian Entry to the Old Testament](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0830825770)

Comment: How do you explain the context? "Then the Jews said to Him, 'You are not yet fifty years old, and have You seen Abraham?'
Jesus said to them, 'Most assuredly, I say to you, before Abraham was, I AM.'”


The New King James Version. (1982). (John 8:57–58). Nashville: Thomas Nelson.

Comment: From Jn 8:12 onward John presents a series of arguments over who Jesus is which culminates in the "I am" statement. Clearly there are rhetorical quips being thrown back and forth like the question about being a Samaritan (Jn 8:48). The comment about Jesus' age appears rhetorical as well. It is also a strange response b/c Jesus says that Abraham "saw it and was glad" - which fits their tradition - but they come back with Jesus "seeing Abraham." The implication is that the tradition of Abraham seeing the vision about the Messiah - Jesus is saying, "he saw me."

Answer (score 1):

When and what did Abraham saw Jesus in John 8:56?

John 8:56 (NKJV)

> Your father Abraham rejoiced to see My day, and he saw it and was
>   glad.”

**Abraham hoped in the resurrection under God's kingdom by the Messiah.**

Abraham, when he and his wife were very old and well beyond the age, as to their ability to produce children, God miraculously restored their reproductive powers. This was like a resurrection.

Hebrews 11:11-12  (NASB)

> 11 "By faith, even Sarah herself received ability to conceive, even
>   beyond the proper time of life, since she considered Him faithful who
>   had promised. 12 Therefore there was born even of one man, and him as
>   good as dead [b]at that, as many descendants as the stars of heaven in
>   number, and innumerable as the sand which is by the seashore."

When their son, Isaac, was about 25 years old, God told Abraham to sacrifice him. Just as Abraham was about to strike Isaac dead,  God's angel prevented him, Abraham considered that God could raise him [Isaac] from the dead. Paul wrote:

Hebrews 11:17-19  (NASB)

> 17 "By faith Abraham, when he was tested, offered up Isaac, and he who
>   had received the promises was offering up his only begotten son; 18 it
>   was he to whom it was said, “In Isaac your [a]descendants shall be
>   called.” 19 [a]He considered that God is able to raise people even
>   from the dead, from which he also received him back **[b]**  as a type."
>   **[b-figuratively]**

**Jesus, God's son from his prehuman vantage point in heaven, noted Abraham's faith in the hope, in a resurrection. As a  man,  Jesus told the Jews;**

John 8:56-58  (NET Bible)

> 56 "Your father Abraham was overjoyed to see my day, and he saw it and
>   was glad.” 57 Then the Judeans[c] replied, “You are not yet fifty
>   years old! Have you seen Abraham?” 58 Jesus said to them, “I tell you
>   the solemn truth, before Abraham came into existence, I am!"

Abraham a **righteous** man, now sleeps in death, awaiting a resurrection to life on earth under God’s Kingdom, by the Messiah.  (​Acts 24:15, Heb. 11:8-10,13)

Acts 24:15  (NASB)

> 15" Having a hope in God, which these men cherish themselves, that
>   there shall certainly be a resurrection of both the **righteous** and
>   the wicked."

Hebrews 11:8-10,  13. (NASB)

> 8 "By faith Abraham, when he was called, obeyed [a]by going out to a
>   place which he was to receive for an inheritance; and he went out, not
>   knowing where he was going. 9 By faith he lived as an alien in the
>   land of promise, as in a foreign land, dwelling in tents with Isaac
>   and Jacob, fellow heirs of the same promise; 10 for he was looking for
>   the city which has foundations, whose architect and builder is God 13
>   All these died in faith, without receiving the promises, but having
>   seen them and having welcomed them from a distance, and having
>   confessed that they were strangers and exiles on the earth."